# D365FO patch method to update Records

Tags: postman, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to update a value for data in D365FO with Patch method as below.

```
https://<URL>/data/DXCGeneralJournalAccountEntries(GeneralJournalAccountEntryRecId = 5637144584)

Body: {
"DXCAdeptiaProcessed": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

error code that i am getting is

> {
>       "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   '/data/DXCGeneralJournalAccountEntries(GeneralJournalAccountEntryRecId = 5637144584)'. No route data was found for this request." }

Can you suggest why this error may be coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried with putting ' around the identifier that you are using?

(GeneralJournalAccountEntryRecId = '5637144584')

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. Since this is not a string it does not need a quote. Works fine for get.

Comment: D365FO requires all the fields in the table to have edit permission even if you want to update one record. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the entity that you're trying to update is a custom entity and it may not have been exposed in the REST OData API.

If you submit a GET request to `/Metadata/Entities` you should be able to find the entity in the results. Here you can check the properties for that entity, it should look something like this:

```
{
  "Name": "DXCGeneralJournalAccountEntries",
  "PublicEntityName": "DXCGeneralJournalAccountEntries",
  "PublicCollectionName": "DXCGeneralJournalAccountEntries",
  "LabelId": "@SYS999999",
  "DataServiceEnabled": true,
  "DataManagementEnabled": true,
  "EntityCategory": "Master",
  "IsReadOnly": false
},
```

Otherwise the documentation might be able to help with exposing the entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#exposing-odata-entities